# Notify Property Update with Async Task

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task

I have a View that contains a ListView in which I load an ObservableCollection.

After that I am going to load some external data from our MySQL Database foreach item in my collection.

I would like to perform these in an async Task to prevent ui freezing.

The updating works fine for all items that are not visible in the ListView. Because they are virtualized?

The items that are currently on the ListView visible are not beeing updated. How can I notify the View to Update the Properties of the items?

Note: the Viewmodel implements InotifyPropertiChanged via a BaseViewModel

```
public class ProductViewModel : BaseTypes.BaseViewModel
{
    public ProductViewModel()
    {
    }

    public void GetProducts(string filter)
    {
        if (filter.Equals(""))
        {
            return;
        }
        Products.Clear();

        Product product = new Product();
        product.GetProductsByHersteller(filter);
        if (product.productsList != null)
        {
            product.productsList.ToList().ForEach(Products.Add);
        }
        GetRanking();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Product> _Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get { return _Products; } private set { _Products = value; } }

    async Task GetRanking()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => GetRank());
    }

    private void GetRank()
    {
        foreach (Product item in Products)
        {
            item.Rank.Get(item.Asin);
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Products));
        }
    }
}
```

Property in the Product class

```
    private Produkt.Ranking rank = new Produkt.Ranking();
    public Produkt.Ranking Rank { get => rank; set => rank = value; }
```

Solution:

Added INotifyPropertyChanged to the Ranking Class.

Code in the ViewModel now is this:

```
public void GetProducts(string filter)
{
    if (filter.Equals(""))
    {
        return;
    }
    Products.Clear();

    Product product = new Product();
    product.GetProductsByHersteller(filter);
    if (product.productsList != null)
    {
        product.productsList.ToList().ForEach(Products.Add);
    }
    GetRanking();
}

private ObservableCollection<Product> _Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get { return _Products; } private set { _Products = value; } }

    async void GetRanking()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => GetRank());
    }

    private void GetRank()
    {
        foreach (Product item in Products)
        {
            item.Rank.Get(item.Asin);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are now executing `GetRank` from another thread, which is not the UI thread. UI updates due to `NotifyPropertyChanged` will fail due to that.

Comment: Look into `Dispatcher.Invoke()` and/or `Dispatcher.BehinInvoke()` this will allow you to update the result on the main thread.

Comment: @XAMlMAX tried with dispatcher same result. UI not being updated

Comment: @XAMlMAX okay BeginInvoke() does work but the ui freezes till the work is done

Comment: Can we see the xaml for the listview control?

Comment: Also the modified code using the dispatcher invokes?

Comment: Just got back on PC, I am off work for a week! The `await` keyword blocks the UI for you, so if you want to use `Dispatcher` then you need to remove `async` and `await`. Let the operation be asynchronous then dispatcher will send the notification to the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *Product* class should implement *INotifyPropertyChanged*.

Then no need to call NotifyPropertyChanged in your GetRank() method.

Comment: I think you should add more info in your question. The dispatcher code that you have tried, the XAML code of your listview, the code of your Product class..

Comment: OMG your answer just pushed me into the right direction. I have now added the INotifyPropertyChanged in the Ranking Class now the UI is updated each item one by one.

Comment: But I am curiouse why the update is not working when I put INotifyPropertyChanged in the Products class that holds a property of the typ Ranking

Comment: Maybe you could add the code of your product class to handle the rank property

Comment: added to the question.

Comment: Ok you should have call NotifyPropertyChanged()  on the Rank property set